# Capture UIView and show it in other UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, capture

Is there any way to capture part of a UIView (UIWebView) and show it in other UIView that presented on its frame bounds?

The UIWebView in presenting an animated view, so I can't use simple screenshot capturing...

Comment: It is unclear what you want to achieve. Add screenshots or some code

Comment: @sj-r I want to duplicate a UIView presentation in another UIView in a different size, for example, a video is playing in a web view, now I want to show it in another view simultaneously without creating another UIWebView to load a URL Request.